# Xamarin: How to remove unwanted packages which is dependent from removed package

Tags: xamarin, dependencies, package

I have added one of the package in the project through the nuget. The package automatically added a couple more packages to my project. I know those packages were dependent to the installing package. If I later on don't need the installed package, how do i safely remove the rest of the packages which dependent to it or does xamarin studio provide the command that can clean up those dependency.

E.g I installed the Google.Apis.CloudSpeechApi.v1beta1. It install the System.IO, System.Net and other System packages at the same time. If I removed the CloudSpeechApi package, those System packages still sitting in my Packages folder and not get cleaned up as well.

Comment: The dependent packages are not removed since you may have later added other packages that may depend on them as well, so the dependencies have to be removed separately. To know which packages were installed as dependencies you can look at the Nuget Gallery page for the package. The dependencies should be listed.

Comment: Ok i see what you mean thanks